# What does T equals T mean in Generics

Tags: swift

I'm studying apple's new language swift, and i looked at the Swift module,
and saw some generic classes have below statements:

```
extension ContiguousArray<T> : ArrayType {

    /// Construct an empty ContiguousArray
    init()
    init<S : Sequence where T == T>(_ s: S) 

    /* other statement skipped */
}
```

I wondering What does the `Where T == T` mean?
I could not figure it out, Could anyone out there help me?

Comment: I believe it is a bug / weirdness in the way that these fake header-like files are generated because code like this does not actually compile.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've tested it in playground, It actually not compile at all.

Answer (score 1):

T is a reference to any type. This allows you to dynamically set a type for something... like an Array. T == T is like saying typeof(Int) == typeof(Int) in obj c